# How to call a method in the child window in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

My angular JS application has a view button. When clicking on the view button, it will call method and that method changes the content in the same page. Now I have a request that when clicking on the view button, it has to open in a new tab and display the contents.

Previous code:

HTML:
`<md-button ng-click="ctrl.ViewClick(item)">View</md-button>`

Controller:

```
  vm.ViewClick = function(item) {   
     // The browser URL is same but it is a new page with the new contents.
     // Calls a angular js service and loads the contents
    
  }
```

Now, I need to call that function in new browser tab.

I made the following changes but didn't worked. Can you please help me on this.

HTML:
`<md-button ng-click="ctrl.NewTabClick(item)">View</md-button>`

Controller:

```
       vm.newTabClick = function(item){
          $Window.open($location.absURL(), 'blank');
          // How do I call  vm.ViewClick function after opening the new browser window?
          };
```

This is the old angular JS. Thanks for helping on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On workaround you can do in this case is, While opening the page pass query parameter in the URL.

```
vm.newTabClick = function(item){
   // Add `viewLink=true` query parameter with true value 
   $Window.open($location.absURL() + '&viewLink=true', 'blank');
   // Store item in sessionStorage     
   window.sessionStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

And then from the component where you want to call the parameter. You can write below code on `$onInit` lifecycle hook.

```
vm.$onInit = function () {
   // Inject $routeParams in dependency areay
   const storedItem = sessionStorage.getItem('item')
   if ($routeParams.viewLink == 'true' && storedItem && storedItem != 'null') {
      vm.viewLink(JSON.parse(storedItem));
   }
}
```

Comment: The browser url is same for all pages. In the new tab, it calls the main page controller. From there I need to call the viewLink function. How do I call the function from one controller to another controller?

Comment: @AshokYaganti to have communication between two controllers, it can be implemented by using either Service or `$rootsScope.$broadcast` / `$rootScope.$emit`

Comment: I tried but didn't worked. But I tried in other way and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AshokYaganti which other way worked for you? It would be great if you can just add it here. It may help others

Comment: I just added init function in the first controller itself and moved viewLink method to first controller.